# INNER JOIN IN MULTIPLE COLUMNS

Tags: sql

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqew9.png)
Hi guys.
I'm developing a clinic management program, I had to join two tables TB_DOCTORS, and TB_SPECIALTY. the problem is; every doctor have more 4 specialties. How can I join the TB_DOCTORS table with more than a specialty

Comment: You should have a third table, `DoctorSpecialties` with one row per doctor and per specialty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TB_DOCTORS.*, 
S1.SPECIALITY_NAME AS SPECIALITY_NAME1, 
S2.SPECIALITY_NAME AS SPECIALITY_NAME2, 
S3.SPECIALITY_NAME AS SPECIALITY_NAME3, 
S4.SPECIALITY_NAME AS SPECIALITY_NAME4 
FROM TB_DOCTORS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_SPECIALTY S1 ON TB_DOCTORS.SPEC_ID1 = S1.SPECIALITY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_SPECIALTY S2 ON TB_DOCTORS.SPEC_ID2 = S2.SPECIALITY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_SPECIALTY S3 ON TB_DOCTORS.SPEC_ID3 = S3.SPECIALITY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_SPECIALTY S4 ON TB_DOCTORS.SPEC_ID4 = S4.SPECIALITY_ID
```

Comment: maybe I can do sth else, instead of storing the values as int, I can store the original nVarChar values??? What do you think?

Comment: No, there's no new table S1, it's just an alias for the existing table. This allows you to use the same table in the join multiple times. Read about table aliases.  As for your other question, no, do not use original nVarChar values, that would be a maintenance nightmare and can cause all sorts of problems later.